# My elastic beanstalk env variables are set, but I can't access them in my python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set environment variables on my elastic beanstalk application using the `eb setenv KEY=VALUE` syntax, and `eb printenv` returns the variables I have set, but I cannot access these variables in my python script.

In my app I have:

```
import os
print os.environ.get("KEY")
```

but it returns an empty value.

Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

See if setting your env variables via the [EB console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html) works